# Get usage overview programmatically

Tags: c#, azure

I currently have a trial account of Windows Azure. Under the category "web sites", you can see the usage overview of your deployed websites:

http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/854/azureo.png

Is it possible to get this info (both the used and max) programmatically somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Currently it is not possible to retrieve this information programmatically as the API behind this (I'm assuming there's an API behind this) is not publicly available.